# this.setState is not re rendering button icon

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to change the class of my button to diplay like/dislike icons however, even when the state is changing when observed from the chrome dev tool the icon doesn't seem to be changing.

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import classnames from "classnames";
    import { addLikeToPost } from "../../../actions/postActions";
    import TextFieldGroup from "../../common/TextFieldGroup";

    class Postpanel extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          isliked: this.props.post.isLiked
        };
      }

      toggleBox = () => {
        this.props.toggleCommentBox(this.props.index);
      };

      addLike = () => {
        this.props.addLikeToPost(this.props.post._id);
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          isliked: !prevState.isliked
        }));
      };

      render() {
        const likeIcon = this.state.isliked == true ? "fa fa-thumbs-up" : "fa fa-heart";

        return (
          <div className="card mb-4 hidden-md-down">
            <div className="card-footer">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <div className="text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-pill btn-secondary" onClick={this.addLike}>
                      <i className={likeIcon} /> Like
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                  <div className="text-center">
                    <button className="btn btn-pill btn-secondary" onClick={this.toggleBox} type="button">
                      <i className="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true" /> Comment
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      auth: state.auth,
      errors: state.errors
    });

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      { addLikeToPost }
    )(Postpanel);
```

I am trying to change the button icon with the likeIcon const.

edit: After digging in, i found the issue. I had a fontawesome js file that was messing with the rendering. All of the solutions posted here are correct.

Comment: Why use state, when everything you need is on props?

Comment: why `false` in `addLike` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you need to use `state` in this case.  Simply use the `props` that are passed in:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import classnames from "classnames";
import { addLikeToPost } from "../../../actions/postActions";
import TextFieldGroup from "../../common/TextFieldGroup";

class Postpanel extends Component {

  toggleBox = () => {
    this.props.toggleCommentBox(this.props.index);
  };

  addLike = () => {
    this.props.addLikeToPost(this.props.post._id);
  };

  render() {
    const likeIcon = this.props.post.isLiked == true ? "fa fa-thumbs-up" : "fa fa-heart";

    return (
      <div className="card mb-4 hidden-md-down">
        <div className="card-footer">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <div className="text-center">
                <button className="btn btn-pill btn-secondary" onClick={this.addLike}>
                  <i className={likeIcon} /> Like
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
              <div className="text-center">
                <button className="btn btn-pill btn-secondary" onClick={this.toggleBox} type="button">
                  <i className="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true" /> Comment
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { addLikeToPost }
)(Postpanel);
```

Your reducer should then set the post to `isLiked=true`.

Comment: due to bad design of my backend thr addLikeToPost function deosn't return a isLiked response. The isLiked comes from the parent component. And it is visibly being set/unset when i click the button but the icon is not changing. Its getting on my nerves :/

Comment: perhaps you should reverse the `isLiked` flag in the action then?  It looks like you have the `__id` in order to find the correct post.

Comment: i tried what you suggested above and the isLiked from the props in now toggling but the icon is still not updating.

Comment: Is the prop changing on re-render?

Comment: Nevermind, i fouund the issue. I had a fontawesome js file in my scripts tags in index.html that was messing with the rendering. All of the solutions posted here are correct. I will update in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the same like

```
<i className={'fa ' + (this.state.isliked ? 'fa-thumbs-up' : 'fa-heart')} />
```

and also change the addLike method as follows

```
addLike = () => {
    this.props.addLikeToPost(this.props.post._id);
    this.setState({
        isliked: !this.state.isliked
    });
};
```

Please try the same and let me know if its not working

Comment: Not working :/ . Also with this both icons disappeared compared to before where they were just set on their initial state.

Answer (score 1):

I would set the state to false initially:

```
this.state = {
  isliked: false
};
```

I would change `addLike` to `handleLike` so you can toggle between true and false depending on the existing state:

```
handleLike = () => {
  this.props.addLikeToPost(this.props.post._id);
  this.setState({ isliked: !this.state.isliked });
}
```

and just change the button to:

```
<button className="btn btn-pill btn-secondary" onClick={this.handleLike}>
```